# New Menu Item Type Meta Box

Tags: menus

I have a project I am working on where I need to pull in articles from a 3rd party API.

I've got this working using rewrites, but the last step I'm having trouble with is integration into the navigation.

What I'd really like is a separate meta box in the left hand column where I could ask for an article id and category and from that information add a custom link to the nav.

Is such a thing possible? I haven't seen much in the way of custom meta boxes from menu items.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should certainly be possible, although as you have noticed it's not too common.

If you take a look at respective admin template the left column is built like this:

```
<?php do_accordion_sections( 'nav-menus', 'side', null ); ?>
```

Essentially they *are* just metaboxes, though differently presented.

The defaults are handled by [`wp_nav_menu_setup()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu_setup/), which should be a good starting point to taking it apart.

Unfortunately I am not confident to weight in on JavaScript side of it, since that's not my area.